# HTTP Status 401 - Authentication failed for this username and password - jBPM - Wildfly

Tags: ant, jboss, wildfly, jbpm, kie

I am trying to run jBPM 6 via Wildfly - jBOSS and KIE, Linux Mint Cinnamon.

Post installation, after I restarted my system, 
I have been asked to enter username and password to log into my local host.

```
HTTP Status 401 - Authentication failed for this username and password.
```

---

I have already tried the following steps

```
chmod 0777 add-user.sh 
./add-user.sh
ant stop.demo
ant clean.demo
ant install.demo.noeclipse
```

I was able to add user and enter a new password, but the problem persists.

Comment: what roles did you give your user?